# How do I maintain consistent email signature html font sizes between a computer and iPhone?

Tags: iphone, font-size

I'm creating a new corporate email signature for our company, and while it looks great on computers, the font sizes change when I look at a test email using my iPhone's native mail application. I'm unaware if Android phones are affected in the same way, but my guess is yes.

Code I'm using:

```
<div style="float:left;padding-right:20px;">
<a href="http://pinetreecommercial.com/twenty"><img alt="Pine Tree Logo. Now in our 20th year of business. Learn more at pinetreecommercial.com/twenty." style="padding-bottom:15px;" src="http://www.pinetreecommercial.com/public-downloads/Signature-Logo-20-Years-ribbon.jpg" /></a>
</div>

<div style="float:left;">
<font size="2" style="font-family:'EB Garamond',serif;color:6CB33F;letter-spacing:1px;margin-bottom:0px;">Graham Grochocinski</font><br />
<font size="1" style="font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;color:7E8083;margin-top:0px;">Creative/Omni-Channel Marketing Director</font>
<p style="font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-size:8pt;color:7E8083;margin-top:5px;">P: 847.574.3338 | M: 708.552.6493 <a href=""><img alt="linkedin icon" style="padding-left:10px;" src="http://www.pinetreecommercial.com/public-downloads/linkedin_12.jpg" /></a>
<a href=""><img alt="twitter icon" style="padding-left:2px;" src="http://www.pinetreecommercial.com/public-downloads/twitter_12.jpg" /></a><br /><a href="http://www.pinetreecommercial.com">www.pinetreecommercial.com</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to maintain a consistent HTML based email signature across a company is futile unless everybody in the company uses exactly the same software (OS and Email client, including versions) and everybody reading the email uses the same software (OS and Email client, including versions) as everybody sending the email.

This is further complicated by the use of software like MS Outlook, which is to email what what IE6 is to Internet Browsers.

You can obtain a degree of consistency using plain text.

Email is a messaging tool, not a marketing tool.